# GETH gets stuck when there is a repetitive transfer, causing other transfers to remain pending

Tags: go, ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum

I'm creating a basic Genesis file with Puppeth. The configuration is as follows:

What would you like to do? (default = stats)

1. Show network stats
2. Configure new genesis
3. Track new remote server
4. Deploy network components

> 2

What would you like to do? (default = create)

1. Create new genesis from scratch
2. Import already existing genesis

> 1

Which consensus engine to use? (default = clique)

1. Ethash - proof-of-work
2. Clique - proof-of-authority

> 2

How many seconds should blocks take? (default = 15)

> 6

Which accounts are allowed to seal? (mandatory at least one)

> 0x19be2f911faFcB3A085964Bf575D7B88E7D83a36
> 0x

Which accounts should be pre-funded? (advisable at least one)

> 0x19be2f911faFcB3A085964Bf575D7B88E7D83a36
> 0x

Should the precompile-addresses (0x1 .. 0xff) be pre-funded with 1 wei? (advisable yes)

> yes

Specify your chain/network ID if you want an explicit one (default = random)

> 5616

Afterwards, I export it like this:

mkdir data
geth --datadir data init genesis.json

And then I start the blockchain like this:

geth --datadir data --port 30311 --networkid 5616 --mine --miner.etherbase 0x19be2f911faFcB3A085964Bf575D7B88E7D83a36 --http --http.addr serverpublicip --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0x19be2f911faFcB3A085964Bf575D7B88E7D83a36 --password password.txt

Geth version is: geth version 1.12.0-stable-e501b3b0

However, when I perform a transaction in Metamask, trying to cancel it or send another transaction causes it not to execute and prevents me from making any further transfers from that wallet. I encountered this issue only once, but sometimes even the initial transfer gets stuck like this.

WARN [07-17|22:53:05.073] Served eth_sendRawTransaction conn=83.66.8.216:21636 reqid=4245504320592 duration=1.308094ms err="replacement transaction underpriced"

I'm receiving the above error message. What could be the reason for this?